# how to keep datagridview record colors while using a buttonfield

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datagridview that has set colors depending on the status of the record. When I add a button field to the datagridview the records keep the chosen autoformat colors of the datagridview. Can anyone tell me how to bypass this problem?

***code for color coordination***

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string correctedString = row.Cells[3].Text.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();

        if (correctedString == "hot")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        }
        else if (correctedString == "pending")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
        }
        else if (correctedString == "active")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumPurple;
        }
        else if (correctedString == "sale")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine;
        }
        else if (correctedString == "nosale")
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a cell you need to update the array index of the following to look in the correct cell:

```
string correctedString = row.Cells[3].Text.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
```

Comment: Haha I know that feeling! No worries. Happy coding!